# Check the checkbox = listviewitem row is selected

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am developing a UWP app.
I have a listview which the listviewitem has a checkbox and the content. What I need to implement is, when I check the checkbox, the related listviewitem is selected; when I uncheck it, the related listviewitem is deselected. My listview need support multi-selection.
Here is my xmal code:

```xml
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SuggestListView" ItemsSource="{Binding SuggestList}" IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled="True"  IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="SuggestListView_SelectionChanged">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ctl:PersonUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <CheckBox Name="CheckBoxhhh" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
       <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
           <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectSuggestPersonCommand}"/>
       </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
   </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

Can anybody throw me some lights？

Comment: Are you aware of [SelectionMode = Multiple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br242915)?

Comment: @Romasz, thank you for comments. How can I use this property to solve this problem? Can you share more details?

Comment: And what is the problem? and why do you need manage all the events? with the binding in Mode Two way is not enough to process changes?

Comment: The *ListVIew* has default multiselection view - if you set `SelectionMode=Multiple`, then you don't need additional checkbox, events and so on. The only difference will be that the default design is that checkbox is on the left, but I think you should be able to edit item's style for that.

Comment: @JuanPabloGarciaCoello,
When the listviewitem is selected, I need to show the selected item in other list.
There are 2 user case:
1. When select a listviewitem, the related checkbox is checked. This is easy to implement by binding the IsChecked of checkbox to the IsSelected property of ViewModel.
2. When the user click the checkbox, the related item should be selected. How can select the item (and show it in other list), when the checkbox is checked?

Comment: Where do you want to access to the other list from viewmodel or is just a view list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track but if you're wanting to use this with the IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled set to true, you don't need to implement your own Checkbox in the ItemTemplate.

From what I gathered from your comments on the question, you're looking for a way to get the items from one collection to another when you're selecting from the other.

So remove the checkbox and also add the SelectionMode="Multiple" to your ListView.

In the Behavior of your ListView, you're listening for the SelectionChanged so remove this from your ListView and it should look like this:

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SuggestListView" ItemsSource="{Binding SuggestList}" IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ctl:PersonUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectSuggestPersonCommand}"/>
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </ListView>
```

Then in your bound Command for the SelectionChanged event you're utilising in the Behavior, you'll want to add the items that are added and removed to an ObservableCollection which you can bind to from your other ListView to show the selected ones.

The method will look something like this:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ItemType> SelectedItems { get; private set; }

    private void SelectedItemsChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (var item in args.AddedItems)
        {
            var vm = item as ItemType;
            if (vm == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            this.SelectedItems.Add(vm);
        }
        foreach (var item in args.RemovedItems)
        {
            var vm = item as ItemType;
            if (vm == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            this.SelectedItems.Remove(vm);
        }
    }
```